What is the relationship between Sitecore index to Solr index core?
I was able to deploy Sitecore 10.3.1 in Azure and I verified the solrConnectionString is pointed to my Solr installation https://mydomain.com:8983/solr. I understand when we deploy onprem locally, Sitecore setup will create the Solr Cores automatically, according to the documentation, I need to manually create those cores in Solr Admin Panel.
I looked the cores in my onprem setup, the folder names have prefix as shown below:

but in Sitecore control panel - Populate Solr Managed Schema I saw the indexes as shown below:

How does Sitecore know sssc1031_core_index is for sitecore_core_index? by matching the last part of the folder name?
According to the document, it instructs to copy _default to server\solr folder and rename it and edit the core.properties file and change id to _uniqueid ...
Since my On-Prem deployment is also Sitecore 10.3.1, can I just copy all core folders under server\solr from my On-Prem Solr to the same location on the Solr box I used for Sitecore 10.3.1 Azure App Service?

Relationship between index name on Solr and the one dispalyed on Sitecore Control panel is derived from the index configuration file. Inside each index configuration there is a property named 'core' which refers to index name(folder name) on Solr and 'name' that refers to index name to be used in Sitecore context, which gets displayed on Sitecore Control Panel.

Hope this helps!!!

I only see 3 configuration files core, master and web but there are many indexes displayed, where are the configuration files?

@John you can find other index configuration details on the following locations.

/App_Config/Sitecore/Marketing.Operations.xMgmt/Sitecore.Marketing.Solr.Index.Web.config
/App_Config/Sitecore/Marketing.Assets/Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.MarketingAssets.Repositories.Solr.Index.Web.config.
Complete details of the all the indexes can be found by browsing /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx page on CM and search for string '<index id' in that page.


The relation between the index and core is it inside the config files
<index id="sitecore_core_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
    <param desc="core">sitecore_core_index</param>
    <param ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" desc="propertyStore" param1="$(id)"/>
       <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration"/>
         <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
           <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/intervalAsyncCore"/>
         </strategies>
         <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
          <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <Database>core</Database>
            <Root>/sitecore</Root>
          </crawler>
        </locations>
   </index>

Have a look here to understand in detail how is working: https://sitecorediaries.org/2020/05/24/how-to-create-a-custom-solr-index/

Thank you very much!  so if the Sitecore.ContentSearch,Solr.Index.Core.config in app service like this:           
$(id)
$(id)

it means my core name in Solr should be sitecore_core_index not sssc1031_core_index?
